# Sub category pictures into main category main content area

Tags: magento-1.9, category, thumbnail

Hi Im building my first Magento store and I have come across the thumbnail in the category section problem.

http://hotelsuppliesstore.com/index.php/bathroom.html

Is the site I'm building I can seem to get the category pictures displaying on the content area.

This is what our other site looks like just to give you an idea on what I'm trying to achieve.

http://www.mellcrest.com/Bathroom__c-p-0-0-19.aspx

Im not too coding savvy so if you could make it in idiots terms that would be great.

Many Thanks

Garry

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you exact want to do. As I understood when you click on the category, the content area should be filled with the product images which are under that category.

This is an in-built feature in Magento. Log into admin panel and check whether you have created the products. (Refer these tutorials if needed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXam876VEoc , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6rhTRXbciQ)

- And if products are created make sure that they are assigned to any
  active category and the visibility is set to `catalog` or
  `catalog,search.`
- Ensure the product is `enabled`
- And check whether the product is `in stock`
- If these things are fine, then the products should be shown in the
  category pages.

Comment: Hi sorry for not making it clear I want the sub category pictures to show up in the Content area of a category. So you can click on one of those to go and see the products. SO if I click on the bathroom category I want to see thumbnails for the sub cat i.e.:Accessories,Clothing, Fittings, Paper Products, Personal Hygiene, Toiletries and Towels.I would like to show the thumbnails for these sub categories in the content area which you could click on and would take you too the products in the category. Just like the Mellcrest site would do.